# Flutter StreamBuilder does not recognize Firebase Auth login

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I am implementing an email-first process to login to my Flutter app with Firebase Auth. For the user flow I am using a StreamBuilder that should recognize if a user is signed in or not. Depending on being signed in or not the user should be redirected appropriately. The problem is that the StreamBuilder does not navigate to the `HomeView()` after a user signed in.

Here is the implementation of my StreamBuilder: If the user is logged in, the app should go to the `HomeView()`, otherwise to `InsertEmailView()`. When not logged in, depending on if the inserted email is used or not, navigate to the `LoginView()` or the `RegisterView()`.
So this is the wanted navigation: `InsertEmailView -> LoginView / RegisterView -> HomeView`.
However, if a user starts in `LoginView()` (without usage of `InsertEmailView()`), the redirection to `HomeView()` works, otherwise not.

```
class _WidgetTreeState extends State<WidgetTree>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: AuthService().authStateChanges, 
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (snapshot.hasData){
          return HomeView();
        } else {
          //return const LoginView(email: "1@1.de");
          return InsertEmailView(onEmailSubmitted: (email) {
            AuthService().isEmailInUse(email).then((isEmailInUse) {
              print(isEmailInUse);
              if (isEmailInUse){
                Navigator.push(
                  context, 
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => LoginView(email: email)
                  )
                );
              } else {
                Navigator.push(
                  context, 
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => RegisterView(email: email)
                  )
                );
              }
            },);
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I implemented an `AuthService()` that implements necessary Firebase Auth methods I need, and even checks if the given email is used or not (which works well).
I implemented `authStateChanges` as follows:

```
class AuthService with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User? get currentUser => _auth.currentUser;

  Stream<User?> get authStateChanges => _auth.authStateChanges();

  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email, 
    required String password
  }) async {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, 
      password: password
    );
  }
  
  Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email, 
    required String password
  }) async {
    await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, 
      password: password
    );
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }

  Future<bool> isEmailInUse(String email) async {
    try {
      List<String> signInMethods = await _auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
      return signInMethods.contains("password"); // usual auth method is "password"
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error checking email: $error');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here you also have the implementation of `LoginView()`:

```
class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  const LoginView({super.key, required this.email});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState(email: email);
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  String? errorMessage = '';
  String email;

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  _LoginViewState({required this.email}){
    _emailController.text = email;
  }

  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    try {
      await AuthService().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text, 
        password: _passwordController.text
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = e.message;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _title(){
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: Text(
        "Logge dich mit\nE-Mail und Passwort ein!",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 

  Widget _entryField(
    String title,
    TextEditingController controller,
    bool obscureText
  ){
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: title,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _errorMessage(){
    return Text(
      errorMessage == '' ?  '' : 'Humm ? $errorMessage',
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton(){
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword();//.then((value) => {
          //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeView()))
        //});
      },
      child: const Text("Anmelden"),
    );
  }

  Widget _switchToRegister(){
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterView(email: email),));
      },
      child: const Text("Doch registrieren?")
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _title(),
            _entryField('E-Mail', _emailController, false),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            _entryField('Passwort', _passwordController, true),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            _errorMessage(),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            _signInButton(),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            _switchToRegister()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can imagine that the `Navigator` breaks the snapshot implementation. I also tried implementing `AuthService` as a variable to not have multiple `AuthServices` in the `StreamBuilder` which also did not work.

Does anyone know how to fix my issue?

Comment: I think it's really hard to assess without seeing the code of `LoginView` as well. But anyway, at the moment you push a route you won't be in your `StreamBuilder` anymore so it makes sense that it doesn't work like that

Comment: What is `AuthService`? Is it a singleton class?

Comment: @Ivo I added the implementation of LoginView

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I also added the implementation of AuthService. It isn't meant to be a singleton class. Should be used as singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this works, but I believe the main problem is that you are pushed to a new route so you are no longer in your `StreamBuilder`, so I think it might be fixed if you simple pop back to it after sign in. That is. change

```
  Widget _signInButton(){
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword();//.then((value) => {
          //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeView()))
        //});
      },
      child: const Text("Anmelden"),
    );
  }
```

to

```
  Widget _signInButton(){
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword().then((value) => {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      },
      child: const Text("Anmelden"),
    );
  }
```

What also is a problem is that you call `AuthService()` all the time which creates a new instance of it every time. It needs to be a singleton. The easiest way to do this is to add these lines to the class

```
  static final AuthService _singleton = AuthService._internal();
  
  factory AuthService() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  
  AuthService._internal();
```

Comment: The `Navigator.pop()` method solves my problem. Thanks a lot!